# Select multiple columns with SELECT WHEN in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to get multiple columns from select when? 
For example, I can get 1 column with this:

```
df1.alias("l")
.join(df2.alias("r"),Seq("id")) 
.select(when($"l.score" > $"r.score", $"l.name").otherwise($"r.name"))
```

But let's say I want to get more than 1 column (or even all attributes from a data frame), I cannot do any of these:

```
df1.alias("l")
.join(df2.alias("r"),Seq("id")) 
.select(when($"l.score" > $"r.score", Seq($"l.id",$"l.name")).otherwise(Seq($"r.id",$"r.name")))


df1.alias("l")
.join(df2.alias("r"),Seq("id")) 
.select(when($"l.score" > $"r.score", $"l.*").otherwise($"r.*"))
```

any idea how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `struct`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.struct

when($"l.score" > $"r.score", struct($"l.name", $"l.score"))
  .otherwise(struct($"r.name", "r.score"))
```

or for all fields:

```
when($"l.score" > $"r.score", struct($"l.*"))
  .otherwise(struct($"r.*"))
```